# Python caching results of large computations (with a twist)

Tags: python-3.x, caching, functools, python-lru-cache

I'm good with Python and use functions to process large datasets from files, then return the results. I've realized these input files and other parameters don't change often, so I could store the returned results for reuse.

I've used @functools.lru_cache before, but I'm facing a challenge now. Even though file paths (passed as input to my functions) remain the same, sometimes I need to ignore the cached values if the file has been updated since the last call. I don't want to complicate my functions by checking for this.

I'm looking for a caching solution that can handle this. If anyone knows an existing solution, I'd love to hear it, so I don't have to create one from scratch.

Using functools.lru_cache complicated things for what I need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.